# Achad Asar Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred eleven?

### ?אחד עשר ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 311.

Give up on lazy gematria; this man can't bear it.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred ten entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.ou.org/torah/tt/5762/shavuot62/print.htm

Parshas Naso is indisputably the longest Sedra, however you count length; is most commonly written on **311** lines in a Sefer Torah (7.4 cols)

Comment: What if you count length by number of parshiyot?

Answer (score 0):

311 is the gematriya of "ish", man. It is also the gematriya of "ha'isha", the woman; whereas "isha" is gematriya 306. "I find "ha'isha" more bitter than death" (Koheles 7:26); when the wife takes on the husband's role in marriage (so her gematriya equals his) its more bitter to him than death (Maharsha in Yevamos 63, I think).

Comment: The Vilna Gaon says something very similar, although I can't remember where.